# how to call a function as argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, lambda

I am learning javascript, i was wondering if it was possible to have something like this use of lambda function

```
function operation (function f, num1, num2){
    f.call(num1, num2);
}
operation((a,b)=>{return a+b}, 2,3);
```

I have *Unexpected token function* at line 1, for **function f** i imagine, is there a way to make this work somehow ?

Comment: In javascript not exist types! replace `function f` by `df`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function operation (f, num1, num2){
    f(num1, num2);
}
operation((a,b)=>{return a+b}, 2,3);
```

JavaScript is **untyped** language. If you want to use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), try this:

```
function operation (f, num1, num2){
    f.call(this, num1, num2);
}
operation((a,b)=>{return a+b}, 2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript function argument definitions do not have types. Remove the keyword `function` from just before the `f` on line 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just remove the `function`:

```
function operation (function f, num1, num2){
  f.call(num1, num2);
}
operation((a,b)=>{return a+b}, 2,3);
```

however this will call your function with the `this`-context `num1`, and the first parameter `num2`. If you want to call the function without overriding the `this` context just call it with `()`:

```
f(num1, num2)
```